# SimpleRetryStrategy Failed<TMessage>

Tags: servicebus, rebus

interface **IHandleMessages** has contravariant parameter TMessage 
`IHandleMessages<in TMessage>`

this makes possible to Register in Ioc Container `IHandleMessages<DerivedType>` and have implementation in Handler : `IHandleMessages<BaseType>`. That is Ok.

The problem consist in `Failed<TMessage>` wrapper for failed Messages, where TMessage is not contravariant. That makes impossible to have
implementation of Handler like `Handler : IHandleMessages<Failed<Base>>`

and registration in Ioc container `.As<IHandleMessages<Failed<DerivedType>>>()`

I think its reasonable to have `Failed<in TMessage>` but not `Failed<TMessage>`

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I did not consider this scenario when I implemented the second-level retries mechanism in Rebus, but I would like to support it.

I've added the feature to 0.99.36 (which will be on NuGet in a few days if the tests pass and everything else looks good).

It looks slightly different from what you proposed though, since co- and contra-variance can only be had with interfaces.

Therefore, Rebus now dispatches an `IFailed<out TMessage>`, because then you can implement e.g. `IHandleMessages<IFailed<AbstractBaseClass>>` when the failed message is `DerivedFromAbstractBaseClass`.

Keep an eye on NuGet.org - it'll be out in a few days :)

In the meantime you can see what the code looks like [in the accompanying test](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus.Tests/Integration/TestSecondLevelRetries.cs#L37-L67).